# How to add logout button if user isn't logged in with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, ejs

I am learning Web development by making projects. I am trying to display Login and Logout button based on the login status of the user on my website. I am using ExpressJs, PassportJs and EJS. I tried this but I am getting error.

EJS code:

```
<form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <% if (login_info) { %>
        <a href="/users/logout" class="btn btn-outline-warning my-2 my-sm-0">Logout</a>
      <% } %>
      <% else { %>
        <a href="/users/login" class="btn btn-outline-warning my-2 my-sm-0">Login</a>
      <% } %>
</form>
```

Server Side Code:

```
router.get('/dashboard', function (req,res){
  if (!req.user) {
    res.render('dashboard', { login_info: 'false' });
  }
  else {
    res.render('dashboard', { login_info: 'true' });
  }
});
```

Error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else' in C:\Users\nodeapp\views\dashboard.ejs while compiling ejs
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Could you specify which error you are getting?

Comment: @tycrek I have added my error above in question.

Comment: Try the EJS If/Else code from [this site](https://www.includehelp.com/node-js/ejs-if-else-statement-ejs-conditions.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing value of login_info as string not as boolean. Can you check if it works

```
router.get('/dashboard', function (req,res){
if (!req.user) { 
res.render('dashboard', { login_info:false });
}
else {
res.render('dashboard', { login_info:true });
}
});
```

And on your ejs keep } else on same line as

```
<% if (true) { %>
<p> valid!!!</p>
<%} else { %>
<p> Not Allowed </p>
<% } %>
```